# How can I customize 'headsep' attribute in the geometry package so that I can set it for individual pages?

Tags: spacing, geometry, package-options

I use the `\geometry` package for formatting my CV, and I know (from [How to remove vertical space between header and body of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33960/3989)) that I can use the `headsep` attribute to customize the spacing between header and the text. But now, I need to have different spacing on the title page of my CV (headsep = 25), and the second page (headsep = 10). How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution would be to issue `\setlength{\headsep}{10pt}` somewhere on the second page. For more sophisticated changes, see section 7 of the geometry [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) *"Changing layout mid-document"*.

Comment: Or `\vspace*{15pt}` when starting the first page.